# Ruby Null-Conditional operator

Tags: ruby

C# has a null-conditional operator that works like this

```
SomeObject?.SomeParam
```

If `SomeObject` is null, then the result of that expression will be null rather than throwing a null reference exception. Does something like this exist in Ruby?

Comment: You're right. I tried searching for this before, but couldn't find anything. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Use `&.` to call a method.

```
some_value&.some_method
```

If `some_value` is `nil`, then `some_method` will not be executed, and the return value of the expression will be `nil`. Otherwise, `some_method` will be called as with when called with `.`.

Comment: Do you have a link to `&.` documentation?

Comment: No, I looked up in http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html, but it seems the official document for that is not ready yet.

Comment: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/NEWS.html describes it briefly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails or ActiveSupport there is `try`, but there is nothing in the Ruby stdlib.

Comment: The "safe navigation operator" is quite new - it was added in Ruby 2.3